# Doctrine schema update Error in prod environnement

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I get an error when I run the command doctrine:schema:update to my console on my hoster. Then, when I try to access my database I have a MySQL error.

```
    # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: trendspopdmaster.mysql.db
    database_port: null
    database_name: MyDbName
    database_user: MyDbLogin
    database_password: *****
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: 90146e6046fs01d1d529c739f1202f94fc74defd
```

My mistake when I want to access my database :

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '\/var\/run\/mysqld\/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

My error when running the command :

```
ATTENTION: This operation should not be executed in a production environment.
           Use the incremental update to detect changes during development and use
           the SQL DDL provided to manually update your database in production.
```

Comment: Do you have an access to the `my.cnf` file?

Comment: no, I'm at OVH with shared offers

Comment: You have to talk to your hoster then..

Comment: @xurshid29 Thank you. the ticket is still pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. it was enough to clear the cache.